# how do I find and split polygons in QGIS

Tags: split, qgis, polygons

I have this shapefile containing what looks like polygons but the attribute table only contain a "level" column.

How would I fine the area of each of the polygons and add that to the attribute table?

Example files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mgcppedd5kvb268/AABmFCXaG39IEV4hV_q2QchPa?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the field calculator. See this help page:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html

All you do is to open the Attribute Table of the shapefile, from there enable the editing mode, open the calculator, add a field and use the $area variable in the expression list.

---

**Addendum**: You have to split one multipolygon to many polygons.

Do do it, go to menu

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to singleparts
```

with it, you create a new shapefile with many polygons inside. Then you can calculate the area in the attribute table, as said before.

Comment: i tried that. But it only calculates the area for all the "polygons" in totals and not each of them.